# Text-align don't work in IE?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

i'm trying to position my "li" to be inline so i have three images in one row and have texts below them (like product catalog view). So far my code is looking fine using chrome but IE on the other hand aligned everything to the left only.

CSS:

```
#products ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#products li{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    display:inline; 
    height:auto;
    padding: 10px 10px;

}
#products img{
    max-width:250px;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;

}
#products ul li p{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:200;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
```

HTML:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
        <div id="products">

            <h2>ALL PRODUCTS</h2>
            <ul>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><a href="<%# Eval("ProductID", "Productdetails.aspx?ProductID={0}")%>"><img src="<%#Eval("ProductImage") %>" /></a>
                 <p><%#Eval("ProductName") %></p>
                 <p>$<%# Eval("ProductPrice") %></p></li>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML, not the whatever-it-is that generates it.

Comment: What version of IE? And what does "does not look nice" mean?

Comment: @Shaggy sorry should've made it clearer, everything is on the left side and the text is next to the image. But on chrome the texts are right below the image.

Comment: Please don't deface your questions like that just because you've "found the error". I've rolled it back for you. - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309255/2802040

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#products li a {
    display: block;
}
```